# Add Margin Between Content and AppBarLayout (Android Design Support Library)

Tags: android, margin, toolbar

I have been implementing the new Android Design Support Library in my app but I have a question about content padding. Right now, my content (cards in a RecyclerView) touches the bottom of the Toolbar in an AppBarLayout until the toolbar is scrolled off the screen. I am trying to add a 16dp margin between the two. If I add a margin to the toolbar, nothing happens. If I add a 16dp view with transparency in the AppBarLayout, it pushes the toolbar content up when it re-enters. If I add a margin to the RecyclerView it pushes the content up and there is a bar between the top of the screen and the content.

Is there an easy way to fix this annoyance?

Thanks!